# pipe script to bash and also use read

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, stdin

If I do this:

```bsh
$ {
> sleep 1
> read -p "Press Enter to continue"
> }
```

I get the prompt after a second, as expected.

Now, if I do this:

```bsh
$ echo 'sleep 1; read -p "Press Enter to continue";' | bash
```

I get a 1 second wait and the script exists, without the input.

Is it possible to both "pipe a script to bash" and also use `read` or something equivalent?

I'm making one of those heretical `curl blah blah | bash` installer things, so I can't do `bash -c 'commands'`. Or can I?

Comment: Your pipeline writes to the standard input of `bash`. So the script is on `bash`'s standard input. Where does `read` read from? Standard input. What's there? The script.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hehe, of course, and you put it well! But how can one resolve this impasse?

Comment: If you want to get interactive input from the user, try `read -p 'Press Enter' </dev/tty`